# Template parameter inference with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates

Considering this small program:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Holder {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > _items;

public:
    void push(A *v) {
        //Perform some checks and other stuff before pushing
        _items.emplace_back(v);
    };
    void push(std::unique_ptr<A> &v) {
        push(v.release());
    };
};

class A {

};

class B : public A {

};

int main()
{
    Holder h;
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;

    // It works but it's too verbose
    h.push(a.release());
    h.push(b.release());

    // It works for a because it has the right type but not for b
    h.push(a);
    h.push(b);
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to write the `h.push(b)` line without the overhead to give ownership myself.

I don't want to use `*b` because the pointer must lose its ownership in the `push` method and I want the `push` method to be as easy as possible to use.

I'm feeling like I should remove the `push` overload taking a `unique_ptr` from `Holder` class and use the first example that works.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why not use move-ops and allow covariance to do all of this. In other words, lose the *first* implementation, not the second, and do this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right signature:

```
void push(std::unique_ptr<A> v) {
    //Perform some checks and other stuff before pushing
    push(std::move(v));
}
```

taking a `unique_ptr` communicates that you are taking ownership.

At call site:

```
// It works but it's too verbose
h.push(std::move(a));
h.push(std::move(b));
```

both because it is required, and because you want ownership-changing code to be clear.

Note that the `std::move(b)` code will result in undefined behavior because `A` lacks a virtual destructor.

```
// It works for a because it has the right type but not for b
h.push(a);
```

this code is toxic, and will cause bugs.  You just silently changed the ownership of a `unique_ptr`.  `auto_ptr` had this property, and was found to be nearly impossible to use properly, and was deprecated then removed from the standard.

Don't write code that makes `unique_ptr` behave like `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight !

I'll go for that :)

How copy constructor of unique_ptr isn't called with std::move ?

Comment: @Masadow Its *move* constructor is instead called.  You probably want to brush up on move semantics of [tag:C++11].

Comment: I must admit that I still stick to pre-c++11 features most of the time, I'll read upon this one :)

Answer (score 2):

You should move instead of passing the object by reference:

```
void push(std::unique_ptr<A> v) {
    push(v.release());
};
```

And then:

```
h.push(std::move(a));
h.push(std::move(b));
```

But any `release` on a unique pointer is a bad smell, so implement the push the other way:

```
void push(A *v) {
    //Perform some checks and other stuff before pushing
    push(std::unique_ptr<A>(v));
};
void push(std::unique_ptr<A> v) {
    _items.push_back(std::move(v));
};
```

And add the virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2):

For `std::unique_ptr`, you should always have ownership, and in this case, you don't need to worry about releasing and making a new pointer. Instead, use the `std::move` function, it was made for this. You can change your push function to this:

```
void push (std::unique_ptr<A> v) { _items.push_back(std::move(v)); }
```

And then you would push in the pointers with:

```
h.push(std::move(a));
h.push(std::move(b));
```